# Appending text at EOL not working

Tags: sed, awk

I'm trying to append a string at the end of each line in a file, but it's not working.
The file has the format

```
1992988282,78.93,SOMETEXT
```

and I tried

```
sed -e 's/$/,2012-09-03/' sample.csv
```

but the text is getting appended and replacing the characters at the beginning of the line. I have tried

```
awk '{ print $0 ",2012-09-03" }' < sample.csv
```

and I'm getting the exact same problem.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this issue. Do you expect the output looking like this: `1992988282,78.93,SOMETEXT,2012-09-03` ?

Comment: MS-DOS line ends (CR+LF)?

Comment: Yes, that is the expected output, but I'm getting `,2012-09-0378.93,SOMETEXT,2012-09-03` instead. Running `echo '1992988282,78.93,SOMETEXT' | sed 's/$/,2012-09-03/'` does work, so I'm guessing this is some "invisible" character in the file messing it up. Any idea what it may be and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you try: cat FILE | od -bc and see what characters are present at the end?

Comment: Thanks, I just saw that I do have `\r\n` and ran `sed 's/\r//; s/$/,2012-09-03/' sample.csv` successfully! Why does having `\r` create this behavior?

Comment: `\r` is carriage return, _not_ line feed. It puts the cursor to the start of the current line. Try `echo 1992988282,78.93,SOMETEXT|sed -e 's/$/\r,2012-09-03/'`

Comment: @user1608941, combine the "s" commands: `sed 's/\r$/,2012-09-03/' sample.csv`

Comment: Run `dos2unix` on your file(s) first to get rid of the spurious control chars that Microsoft throws at the end of lines. Then run your UNIX tool(s) on the file(s).

Comment: MS-DOS represents EOL using two characters, CR and LF.  They stand for 'carriage return'  and 'Line Feed'.  This maps to the way mechanical typewriters work, to move to the next line, first a line feed action happens and then the carriage is returned to starting position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/[[:cntrl:]]*$/,2012-09-03&/' sample.csv
```

so you keep the ended control char in place (unless you want to use it without, than the last `&` is to be removed)